# RewriteRule no mantiene la URL en el navegador

Tags: .htaccess, url, rewriterule

necesitaba convertir unas URLS en URLs amigables pero cuando accedo a la URL amigable me redirige siempre a la original, no me mantiene nunca la amigable.

Tengo el código tal que así:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks


RewriteRule ^prueba2/(.+)$ https://foodnbike.com/prueba/?e=$1 [R=301]
```

un ejemplo:

Original: https://foodnbike.com/prueba/index.php?e=1

Amigable: https://foodnbike.com/prueba2/1

si entras por la amigable, te redirige a la original, nunca me mantiene la URL amigable que es lo que buscaba.

Gracias!

Comment: Sería de ayuda si pusieras un ejemplo de la url original y la que pretendes conseguir.

Comment: Primero gracias por contestar,
un ejemplo seria este, es funcional ahora mismo, puedes probar la url en el navegador

Original: https://foodnbike.com/prueba/index.php?e=1
Amigable: https://foodnbike.com/prueba2/1

si entras por la amigable, te redirige a la original.

pongo tb la linea del codigo de este: RewriteRule ^prueba2/(.+)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}/prueba/?e=$1 [R=301]

Comment: %{REUQEST_URI} incluye prueba2/1 y en la redirección la vuelves a poner con lo que el servidor vuelve a verla y te vuelve a redirigir.  Yo pondría RewriteRule ^prueba2/(.+)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/prueba/?e=$1 [R=301]

Comment: Vi el fallo de %{REUQEST_URI} y lo cambie por ^prueba2/(.+)$ https://foodnbike.com/prueba/?e=$1 [R=301] y dejo de replicarme el directorio pero me sigue redirigiendo la URL a la original

Ya probé tu código también pero me sigue redirigiendo al original, muchas gracias.

Comment: A lo mejor lo entendí mal: si escribo  foodnbike.com/prueba2/1  me debe redirigir a https://foodnbike.com/prueba/index.php?e=1 ¿Es eso?

Comment: si escribes  foodnbike.com/prueba2/1 deberia quedarse con esa URL y cargar como si fuera foodnbike.com/prueba/index.php?e=1  
porque lo que quiero es que la URL original quede amigable y no con el codigo del GET

Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: Entonces lo que querías era enmascarar la url, y ese era el camino evitar que el servidor envie una redirección al navegador.

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda, aún voy bastante verde en htaccess :)

Answer (score 0):

conseguí quitar la redirección de la URL, era quitando el server name del inicio

dejandolo así:

```
RewriteRule ^prueba2/(.+)$ /prueba/?e=$1 [L]
```

Gracias!